# How to Reset the seekBar and disable it when another mediplayer is Running?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-mediaplayer

I have a List of Voice Recordings. Everything works well until, when one MediaPlayer is running and i clicked on another MediaPlayer without pausing the current one, seekbar of the current MediaPlayer also runs with the new MediaPlayer.

I tried everything possible i could from setting certain conditions to it but nothing is really working.
Please anyone there to Help me!

Comment: Can you please explain to us how is this question related to Firebase?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.